# How to clear the MS Office Clipboard using c# Word Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, clipboard, office-interop

I'm working with Word Interop to copy an entire document to do some logic. After I'm done, I want to clear the MS Office clipboard. This seems like a simple task... but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
var that = document.ActiveWindow.Selection;
that.WholeStory();
that.Copy();
// Do some logic with the selection
...
// Now I want to clear the MS Office clipboard.
```

**Note 1:** Clipboard.Clear() only clears the system-wide clipboard, but does not clear MS Office's clipboard.

**Note 2:** I realize that copying a document isn't the best way to work with the Document object, once I figure out *this* issue, I'll work on better logic.

Comment: If it is system-wide clipboard, then try to use Clipboard.Clear()

Comment: Clipboard.Clear() clears it from the system-wide clipboard so that a user can't just click paste anymore, but it doesn't clear it from the MS clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

The Office Clipboard is not exposed to the developer - there's no way to clear it, or to place any content specifically on it, or to "read" what it contains.

Whether there's a "better way" to copy a Word document depends very much on what you want/need to do with the content...